# Changing facebook application display name after App Center submit

Tags: facebook, center

I submitted my application to Facebook's App Center and now I need to update the application name.  When I go to the application settings, and click 'edit' the display name is greyed out.  I'm guessing I need to cancel my submission and resubmit but when I click on the "Cancel Submission" a load dialog appears and the page just hangs.

Comment: Having this issue here as well. Chrome / Safari / FF on OSX